# Can we install MySQL different versions on Linux CentOS5.8?

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, centos

I am trying to install a software which required MySQL-server, MySQL-client installed on the server so now I want to install  MySQL-server and MySQL-client using  rpm files "MySQL-server-5.5.17-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm" and "MySQL-client-5.5.17-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm".

I have installed MySQL-client but when I try to run mysql-server

```
  *rpm -i MySQL-server-5.5.17-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm*
```

it's showing error:

```
  *error: Failed dependencies:
     MySQL conflict with mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.x86_64
     MySQL conflict with mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
     MySQL conflict with mysql-server-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.x86_64*
```

So how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question - is the version of MySQL already installed actually in use or was it simply there as a result of a fresh CentOS install? If the former, try upgrading rather than installing. If the latter, uninstall the old version (possibly using the `--no-deps` option on `rpm`) and then install the newer version

Next, are you trying to replace MySQL or install another version alongside it?

If the former, again try upgrading rather than installing. If that's not possible, you're going to have to remove the older version and then install the new version

If the latter, and if it *is* possible, look at the `--prefix` and `--relocate` options in RPM.as they may help.

If you do to mange to get it installed side by side with an older, you'll have fun and games ensuring that the relevant versions are pointing to the correct libraries and that you don't get any corruption between them. Also, you **will** need to run them so that they listen on separate ports with separate database folders, PID and socket files etc.

Whatever you need to do, do it out of business hours with as many backups as you can do

Comment: Yes MySQL5.0 which is already installed is in use with one application. So i can't uninstall MySQL5.0, that's why I want to install MySQl-server5.5 and MySQL-client5.5

Comment: If you can, spool up a virtual machine on something with CentOS 5.5 and try some things. Do it on a virtual machine so that you can take snapshots and have points in time to return to in case it all goes wrong.

Comment: means there is no option to keep two different versions of MySQL? because there is no virtual machine installed on server right now.

Comment: Try it on your local desktop machine. Or at home. Anywhere that is not the production machine. You don't want to be messing around with a live server installing software if you really don't need to. Trying things out on a virtual machine means that you get the chance to investigate without the risk of making a live machine unusable *and* you can work out the steps required so that you can do the change on a live server (if possible) as quickly as possible. DO NOT MESS WITH A LIVE SERVER! If you do, you may as well just push the big red power button for the server room!

Answer (score 2):

the error given by you *error: Failed dependencies:
     MySQL conflict with mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.x86_64
     MySQL conflict with mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
     MySQL conflict with mysql-server-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.x86_64*

It clear show that the machine you are going to install mysql 5.5 rpm have  mysql 5.0.77 installed .

to resolve this problem .
1. you take backup of datadir and my.cnf (if you are using mysql 5.0 db server earlier).
2. remove all mysql 5.0 server packages , to remove these package you should knew what are the packages already installed on machine
to view all mysql package already installed use  rpm -qa | grep -i  "mysql*"   this command show what package is already installed on machine 
 now you have to remove all package which name shows in above command.

to remove a package/rpm  use rpm -e mysql-5.0.**** if show error then use
rpm -e --nodeps mysql-5.0.****

we have to remove all packages one  by one by using rpm -e .

1. after successful remove all older version of mysql , now start installation of mysql-5.5*** packages by using rpm -ivh mysql-5.5***.rpm.